# Sum varchar time to a timestamp in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to sum a timestamp with a time that I have to cast from varchar to time. This is my attempt:

```
select 
    my_timestamp + cast(my_str_time as time) as my_end_time
from my_db.my_table;
```

`my_timestamp` format (already a `timestamp`):

```
2022-07-16 02:51:11
2022-07-16 03:18:06
...
```

`my_str_time` format (which is a varchar of 50 in the `HH:mm:ss` format):

```
00:03:51 
00:04:13
...
```

The error I'm getting:

```
specified types or functions (one per info message) not supported on redshift tables
```

Is there any way to calculate this or I would have to alter that varchar column to time?

Comment: Is my_db.my_table a system table?  If so this would better match the error message.  I also expect you really want to cast to the interval data type, not time.

Comment: @BillWeiner it's not a system table actually, however casting to interval did the trick :) thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use a combination of **to_timestamp** and extract (not too pretty but it should work):

```
extract(sec from to_timestamp(my_str_time,'hh:mi:ss')),
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me (very inefficient):

```
with my_times as (
    select
        my_timestamp as my_start_time,
        my_time,
        SUBSTRING(my_time, 0, 3)::integer as my_time_hour,
        SUBSTRING(my_time, 4, 2)::integer as my_time_min,
        SUBSTRING(my_time, 7, 2)::integer as my_time_sec
    from my_db.my_table
)
select
    my_start_time,
    my_time,
    dateadd(HOUR, my_time_hour, dateadd(MINUTE, my_time_min, dateadd(SECOND, my_time_sec, my_start_time))) as my_end_time
from my_times;
```

Or even better as Bill suggested:

```
select
    my_timestamp,
    my_time,
    my_timestamp + cast(my_time as interval) as my_end_time
from my_db.my_table
limit 5;
```